# Function to apply log transformation over multiple variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, logarithm

I'm trying to apply log transformation over multiple columns from a Dataframe in Python with this function.

```
def log(x):
       if type(x) is float64 or int64:
              apply(np.log(x+1))
       else:
              return x

df2.apply(log)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NameError: ("name 'float64' is not defined", 'occurred at index CUSTID')
```

`CUSTID` is the first categorical column in the DataFrame

Comment: Is this a pandas data frame or a numpy 2D array?

Comment: Unrelated, but `type(x) is float64 or int64` is parsed as `(type(x) is float64) or int64` - that is it  first check `bool((type(x) is float64))`, then `bool(int64)`. The correct test would be `if type(x) is float64 or type(x) is int64`.

Comment: it's a pandas Dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The `NameError` is probably due to an import error. If you have

```
import numpy as np
```

you need to refer to the data types as `np.float64` and `np.int64`. Otherwise, your import should be

```
from numpy import float64, int64
```

Also, it is more common style to write

```
if isinstance(x, np.float64) or isinstance(x, np.int64)
```

or (equivalent but simpler)

```
if isinstance(x, (np.float64, np.int64))
```

which also works for subclasses (though I doubt this will make any difference in this case)

Comment: or just `isinstance(x, (nb.float64, nb.int64))`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: thanks. I didn't know that (I try to avoid `isinstance`). Added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do the work

```
for c in [c for c in df.columns if np.issubdtype(df[c].dtype , np.number)]:
    df[c] = np.log(df[c])
```

Example Code :
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
[2, 4, "A"],
[4, 5, "C"],
[5, 4, "B"],

[10, 4.2, "A"],
[9, 3, "B"],
[3, 3, "C"]
], columns=['data1', 'data2', 'Categories'])

for c in [c for c in df.columns if np.issubdtype(df[c].dtype , np.number)]:
    df[c] = np.log(df[c])
```

Output:

```
      data1     data2 Categories
0  0.693147  1.386294          A
1  1.386294  1.609438          C
2  1.609438  1.386294          B
3  2.302585  1.435085          A
4  2.197225  1.098612          B
5  1.098612  1.098612          C
```

Comment: what if you have zeros?

Comment: if you want to ignore zeros this trick will do the work : 
`for c in [c for c in df.columns if np.issubdtype(df[c].dtype , np.number)]:`
    `df[c] =df[c].replace(0,1)`
    `df[c] = np.log(df[c])` ***add*** this : `df[c] =df[c].replace(0,1)`